# Не работает форма для входа в приложении (FIrebase)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

При нажатии на кнопку войти у меня должны провериться данные с базой firebase, и в случае, когда все правильно, перейти в другое активити, а если нет, то выдать ошибку. Но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит? Что я забыл?

Вот код входа и всего активити с переходами кнопок

```
@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_create:
                Intent Create = new Intent(this, MainActivityCreateAccount.class);
                startActivity(Create);
                break;
            case R.id.textForgot:
                Intent Forgot = new Intent(this, MainActivityForgotPassword.class);
                startActivity(Forgot);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString())) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root_element), getString(R.string.Email_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (editEntranceTextTextPassword3.getText().toString().length() < 5) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root_element), getString(R.string.password_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //Вход
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString(), editEntranceTextTextPassword3.getText().toString())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivityEntrance.this, MainActivityForgotPassword.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root_element), getString(R.string.Authorisation_error) + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


    }

}
```

Comment: "Нажал на кнопку и ничего не происходит" - это слова юзера, программисту такое говорить должно быть стыдно. Есть два замечательных инструмента: logcat и дебаггер - научитесь ими пользоваться. Это позволит вам определять что именно у вас не[так] работает, куда код заходит, куда не доходит, какие значения переменных приводят к нежелательному результату и т.д. и т.п. Множество вопросов отпадёт само по себе, если вы научитесь находить причину неполадки.

Comment: @woesss я все равно не понимаю, хоть и использовал logcar и дебаггер